# JS find() not working on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, `clients`, which I want to run `array.find()` on. This array contains objects, and usually looks something like this:

```
[ { customId: 'user1', clientId: 'TPGMNrnGtpRYtxxIAAAC' },
  { customId: 'user2', clientId: 'G80kFbp9ggAcLiDjAAAE' } ]
```

This is where I encounter a problem. I am trying to use `find()` to see if any object (or part of an object) in the array matches a certain variable, `recipient`, which usually contains a value like `user1`. the code I am using to do this is:

```
function checkID(recipient) {
       return recipient;
        }
    var found = clients.find(checkID);
```

This always returns the first object in the array. Am I using `find()` wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `recipient` refers to the object, so `return recipient` will always result in a `true` result, meaning the first iteration through `find()` will return `true` and stop. What are you trying to check? Maybe you want something more like `return recipient.clientId === clientIdVariable`, as an example.

Comment: @TylerRoper Sorry, I accidentally posted the question before I was done with it. :/

Comment: `find` takes a function that receives an element from the array and returns a boolean indicating whether the element matches a condition. Your `checkId` function always returns the element it receives, which gets cast to a boolean, which will be true as long as the element itself isn’t falsy (false, null, 0, undefined), so it’s no surprise that this always returns the first element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` takes a predicate (a function that returns true if item is a match and false if item is not a match).

```
const arr = [ { customId: 'user1', clientId: 'TPGMNrnGtpRYtxxIAAAC' },
              { customId: 'user2', clientId: 'G80kFbp9ggAcLiDjAAAE' } ]

const result = arr.find(item => item.customId === 'user1')
                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                             // This should evaluate to true for a match and to false for non-match
```

The reason you're getting the first item of your array all the time, is because your `checkId` function is returning something which evaluates to `true`. So, the first item is evaluated and produces a **truthy** result, and therefore it gets picked as the first match.

---

If unfamiliar with the lambda syntax `() => {}`, then that line is similar to:

```
const result = arr.find(function (item) { return item.customId === 'user1' })
```

Comment: The function must return true if match, and false if not match

Comment: @TylerRoper Right, I misread OPs code initially. Thanks to your tip, I edited the response. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using find wrong.
If **recipient** contains information about the target value you should name the first param of checkID with a different name. And compare any property of it with recipient.

```
var found = clients.find(function(element) { return element.prop1 === recipient.anyProp;  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the objects in the array for the presence of a certain `customId`, put the value you're searching for in an object, and pass that object to `find()`:

```js
let clients = [{
    customId: "user1",
    clientId: "TPGMNrnGtpRYtxxIAAAC"
  },
  {
    customId: "user2",
    clientId: "G80kFbp9ggAcLiDjAAAE"
  }
];

function checkID(el){
  return el.customId === this.param;
}

let found = clients.find(checkID, {param: "user1"});
console.info(found);
```